# Null Pointer Exception when editing text in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

Here's a picture of the interface of my program, just for simplicity when explaining my problem.  [image: Interface of my program]

So the program starts with this screen, and the first step is to edit your name, by clicking the edit name button, which calls this method:

```
private void editName() {
     NameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
     NameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
     Sumbit = new javax.swing.JButton();
     Sumbit.addActionListener(this);

     setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     setAlwaysOnTop(true);
     setType(java.awt.Window.Type.POPUP);

     NameLabel.setText("Name:");
     NameField.setText(name);
     Sumbit.setText("Sumbit");
     ..location code..
```

So you type your name in the text field that pops up, and you hit submit. Then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException  
at kraz.Kraz.game(Kraz.java:62)  
at kraz.Kraz.actionPerformed(Kraz.java:186)
```

The actionPerformed on line 186 is the submit button:

```
        else if (e.getSource() == Sumbit)
    {
        name = NameField.getText();
        NameField.setText("" + name);

        if (step == 1)
        {
            ++step;
            game();
        }
    }
```

Line 62 is where I call the game() method. The next one, line 162 is:

```
public void game() {
    if (step == 1)
    {
        HealthBar.setValue(100);
    }
    else if (step == 2)
    {
        EventField.setText("Test");
        ProgressBar.setValue(1);
    }
}
```

and the error is when I set the text in EventField.

Full Code: http://pastebin.com/rBWju8vX

Comment: Is `EventField` initialized? That's the only thing that can be `null` on line 62 as indicated in the stack trace.

Comment: It's initialized in initComponents().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 constructors, one calls `initComponents()` and the other doesn't:

```
public Kraz() {
    initComponents();
    setVisible(true);
    game();
}

public Kraz(String check) {
    if (check.equals("editName"))
    {
        editName();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In the main method, you call `new Kraz();` which is the one that calls `initComponents()`. But when you handle the EditName event, you call the constructor again but the other one, `new Kraz("editName")`, which doesn't call `initComponents()` so the EventField is null:

```
else if (e.getSource() == EditName)
{
    new Kraz("editName");
}
```

So when, in this new instance of `Kraz`, you hit the "Submit" button, the new instance handles the event and calls `game()`, except none of the fields have been initialized.

Comment: This is just bad coding on my part, what I do is the first one is the main one, and the second constructor creates the popup window that is the edit name window

Comment: You should be calling this(); in the second constructor.  This will alleviate the need to recode what the first constructor is doing.

Comment: I'm confused on where I would be calling the this() method. Would it be when creating the new instance of Kraz, and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @RipIt You'd call it the first thing in the `Kraz(String check)` constructor. But you really should make the "Edit Name" dialog a separate class and not try to repurpose the `Kraz` class to do multiple things.

Comment: @JonLin Alright I'm going to just create a separate class. When I placed <code>this();</code> into my code I got several different errors and it reopened the other window again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RipIt Check my "other" answer

Answer (score 0):

Call `this()` in the second constructor:

```
public Kraz() {
    initComponents();
    setVisible(true);
    game();
}

public Kraz(String check) {

    this(); // <-- Add here

    if (check.equals("editName"))
    {
        editName();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Said that adding `this()` caused a bunch of errors. If @RipIt really wanted to repurpose the Kraz class for the edit name window, just need to instantiate a `EventField` in `editName()`, where a bunch of other fields get initialized.

Comment: It's because this() wasn't called meant that the components been accessed weren't been initialized, thus causing a null pointer exception.